# How do I generate group table for elliptic curves over finite fields

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups, elliptic-curves

Can someone please explain how to generate a group table for an elliptic curve over a finite field? The number of solutions or points are about 16 and it is not possible to do them by adding each individually. Complete novice about elliptic curves, some help would be appreciated thank you.

> > For instance how would i go about solving this $y^2\equiv x^3 +2\pmod {7}$ over a finite field? It has 9 points.

Comment: No and can't use it either. It has to be done manually

Answer (score 6):

Your example curve is given by $\mathcal E: y^2 = x^3 + 2$.

First, find all of the points on the curve over the finite field $\mathbb F_7$. Working modulo 7 we have
$$\begin{array}{|c|ccccccc|}
\hline x,y & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\hline
y^2 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 4 & 1 \\
\hline
x^3+2 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 1 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

We want all pairs of points $[x,y]$ for which $y^2 \equiv x^3+2 \pmod 7$. The table gives us
$$\mathcal E/\mathbb F_7 =\{\mathcal{O}, [0, 3], [0, 4], [3, 1], [3, 6], [5, 1], [5, 6], [6, 1], [6, 6]\}$$

There are standard formulae for combining any two points. See [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#The_group_law) of Wikipedia.

You can save yourself some time by noting that if the line through any two points $P$ and $Q$ is vertical then $P + Q=\mathcal{O}$. For example $(0,3) + (0,4) = \mathcal{O}$. Moreover, since the group operation is commutative (i.e. $P + Q = Q + P$), we get $(0,4) + (0,3) = \mathcal{O}$ for free. Similarly for $(3,1) + (3,6)$, $(5,1) + (5,6)$ and $(6,1) + (6,6)$. Obviously $\mathcal O + P = P = P + \mathcal O$ for all $P$.

This gives us $25$ out of the $81$ entries in the group table without having to apply a single formula. Of the remaining $56$ entries, you need only compute $32$ explicitly, because if you know $P+Q$ you also know $Q+P$. In reality, you don't even need to find all of these $32$ since if you have one space in any row/column then you can complete that row/column since every row/column must contain each element once, and only once; you only need find $24$ explicitly, i.e. $30\%$ of the entries.

Applying the formulae from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#The_group_law) gives me the group table
$$\begin{array}{|c|ccccccccc|} \hline
& \mathcal{O} & [0, 3] & [0, 4] & [3, 1] & [3, 6] & [5, 1] & [5, 6] & [6, 1] & [6, 6] \\ \hline
\mathcal O & \mathcal{O} & [0, 3] & [0, 4] & [3, 1] & [3, 6] & [5, 1] & [5, 6] & [6, 1] & [6, 6] \\
[0,3] & [0,3] & [0,4] & \mathcal O & [6,1] & [5,6] & [3,1] & [6,6] & [5,1] & [3,6] &
\\
[0,4] & [0, 4] & \mathcal O & [0, 3] & [5, 1] & [6, 6] & [6, 1] & [3, 6] & [3, 1] & [5, 6] \\
[3,1] & [3, 1] & [6, 1] & [5, 1] & [3, 6] & \mathcal O & [6, 6] & [0, 3] & [5, 6] & [0, 4] \\
[3,6] & [3, 6] & [5, 6] & [6, 6] & \mathcal O & [3, 1] & [0, 4] & [6, 1] & [0, 3] & [5, 1] \\
[5,1] & [5, 1] & [3, 1] & [6, 1] & [6, 6] & [0, 4] & [5, 6] & \mathcal O & [3, 6] & [0, 3] \\
[5,6] & [5, 6] & [6, 6] & [3, 6] & [0, 3] & [6, 1] & \mathcal O & [5, 1] & [0, 4] & [3, 1] \\
[6,1] & [6, 1] & [5, 1] & [3, 1] & [5, 6] & [0, 3] & [3, 6] & [0, 4] & [6, 6] & \mathcal O \\
[6,6] & [6, 6] & [3, 6] & [5, 6] & [0, 4] & [5, 1] & [0, 3] & [3, 1] & \mathcal O & [6, 1] \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Notice that all of the elements of the group $\mathcal E/\mathbb F_7$ have order three. There are only [two finite groups of order nine](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_9). Since no element of the group $\mathcal E/\mathbb F_7$ has order nine, it cannot be cyclic. Hence $$\mathcal E/\mathbb F_7 \cong \mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$$

Answer (score 2):

Another approach (see Example $15.5$ at [*Elliptic Curve Cryptography*](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9781848002722-c15.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-737921-p173817961)), is the following.

Take $x = 0 \ldots 6$ and for each $x$ solve: $$y^2 \equiv x^3 + 2 \pmod {7}$$

You can set-up two tables (note: each $y$ can produce zero, one or two points):

- $x = 0 \implies y^2 = 2 \pmod 7$
- $x = 1 \implies y^2 = 3 \pmod 7$
- $x = 2 \implies y^2 = 3 \pmod 7$
- $x = 3 \implies y^2 = 1 \pmod 7$
- $x = 4 \implies y^2 = 3 \pmod 7$
- $x = 5 \implies y^2 = 1 \pmod 7$
- $x = 6 \implies y^2 = 1 \pmod 7$

We also calculate for $y = 0 \ldots 6$:

- $y = 0 \implies y^2 = 0 \pmod 7$
- $y = 1 \implies y^2 = 1 \pmod 7$
- $y = 2 \implies y^2 = 4 \pmod 7$
- $y = 3 \implies y^2 = 2 \pmod 7$
- $y = 4 \implies y^2 = 2 \pmod 7$
- $y = 5 \implies y^2 = 4 \pmod 7$
- $y = 6 \implies y^2 = 1 \pmod 7$

This yields (just match the two tables up) the following sets of points:

- $x = 0, y = 3, 4$
- $x = 1, y = -$
- $x = 2, y = -$
- $x = 3, y = 1, 6$
- $x = 4, y = -$
- $x = 5, y = 1, 6$
- $x = 6, y = 1, 6$

This gives us eight points and we add the point at infinity, $I = (\infty, \infty)$, for a total of nine points.

You can use [*Hasse's Theorem*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse%27s_theorem_on_elliptic_curves) to quickly bound the number of points over $\mathbb{F}_{q}$, where $q = 7$ in your example and is given by:

$$q + 1 - 2 \sqrt{q} \le \#E(\mathbb{F}_q) \le q + 1 + 2 \sqrt{q}$$

You can also look into [*Point Counting Algorithms*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_points_on_elliptic_curves) to determine the actual number of points on the curve.

It is worth mentioning that you can get free computer algebra tools like [*SAGE*](http://www.sagemath.org/), (there is now a cloud based online variant), [*GP/Pari*](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) and others.

Lastly, you should compare the solution above with what @Travis wrote up.

Answer (score 1):

For any group with $9$ elements, one can simply pick a nonidentity element $g$ and compute the subgroup it generates. Note that there are only two groups of this order $\mathbb{Z}_9$ and $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$, and that the former has exactly $2$ elements of order $3$.

If $g$ has order $9$, your group is isomoprhic to $\mathbb{Z}_9$, with generator $g$, which gives you the table immediately, as we can write any sum as
$(ag) + (bg) = (a + b)g$, $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}_9$.

If $g$ has order $3$, then pick an element $h$ not in the subgroup $\{0, g, 2g\}$. If $h$ has order $9$, proceed as above. If $h$element has order $3$, then the group has at least three elements of order $3$ (namely, $g$, $2g$, $h$), so the group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$, and can be identified with $\langle g \rangle \times \langle h \rangle$, which again gives a complete multiplication table: $(ag, bh) + (cg, dh) = ((a + c)g, (b + d)h)$, $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't get it. I need to generate a group table for two groups of order 3 which is isomorphic to group of order 9. I know the points for order 9 but i have to find them for two groups of order 3 and then generate a table accordingly

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you mean. Do you mean, you know that your group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$?

Comment: Yes it was mentioned by the instructor.

Comment: Great, so pick out one generator of each factor, and then write down the table.

Comment: So I have to consider both the groups separately and generate the points separately according to the curve? And then consolidate the answers?

Comment: That's one way to do it. But do you know what the multiplication table for $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$ looks like?

Comment: No, not really. Just know how the ones for a single group are done. Can you explain how to do this one in those terms so I can relate to it easily?

Comment: The idea is that in a direct product of two groups, the group multiplication works independently in the two factors, so that $(a, b) + (c, d) = (a + c, b + d)$. In other words, $a$ doesn't "see" $b$ or $d$.

Comment: For an explicit table, using slightly different notation, see http://www.math.niu.edu/~beachy/aaol/grouptables1.html; search for "the direct product of two cyclic groups of order 3".

Comment: So for instance suppose that I have calculated a point (1,8) in order 9. I will find an entirely new set of points which will have no relation to order 9 points right?So a and b are elements of one group and c and d of the other group?

Comment: Can you post a link for an example involving an elliptic curve over primes whose table is generated in this method?

Comment: If the group has order $9$ and you've found an element $g$ with order $9$, then by definition $g$ generates the group, and you're in the first scenario. And sorry, I don't know of any such link.